# matlab execute script from linux command line

Tags: linux, matlab

is there a way to run a matlab script from linux command line?
For instance, I have the following simple script "test.m":

```
x = [1,2,3];
y = [2;3;4];

prod = x*y
disp(prod)
```

So what I want is to be able to execute that script from the linux command line without opening the matlab GUI or the matlab command line. That is, I expect something like that:

```
~$ matlab test.m
```

and I expect to see the result of the product on the linux command line.

I know that you can do that with python e.g.,

```
~$ python test.py
```

but was wondering if the same can be achieved with matlab.

Comment: If you have the Matlab Linux version installed, you just https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html Note if you are running a windows version using Wine or some other VE, you will not be able to use this feature :(

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In order to run a script you can open Matlab (you can prevent run it without the GUI using   `-nodisplay` and `-nodesktop` flags), then run the script using the `run` command, and finally close matlab using `exit`.

You can do all this from a terminal with a single instruction:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('path/to/your/script.m');exit;"
```

However Matlab outputs the welcome message to the console before running your script. To get rid of the welcome message just skip the first 11 lines (10 depending on your Matlab version) using `tail -n +11`

So your final instruction will be:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('path/to/your/script.m');exit;" | tail -n +11
```

Comment: :D you can also add nojvm in there to keep RAM consumption low, but loses Java handles.

Comment: It seems to be important to make the path to your script absolute and note relative as suggested here since Matlab doesn't search for files relative to the directory in which it was started (depending on your configurations).

Comment: You may want to use `-batch` instead of `-r` so the commands run non-interactively and you get a cleaner output ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/commonly-used-startup-options.html)).

Answer (score 38):

Starting with R2019a, the preferred method would be, for your test.m script:

```
matlab -batch "test"
```

This has several advantages, mainly no need for all the `-no` flags and MATLAB will exit with non-zero status if *test.m* (must be on search path) contains an error.

From the documentation page, [matlab (Linux)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html):

> Execute MATLAB script, statement, or function non-interactively.
>   MATLAB:
>
> - Starts without the desktop
> - Does not display the splash screen
> - Executes *statement*
> - Disables changes to preferences
> - Disables toolbox caching
> - Logs text to `stdout` and `stderr`
> - Does not display dialog boxes
> - Exits automatically with exit code 0 if *script* executes successfully. Otherwise, MATLAB terminates with a non-zero exit code.
>
> *statement* is MATLAB code enclosed in double quotation marks. If *statement* is the name of a MATLAB function or script, do not specify the file extension. Any required file must be on the MATLAB search
>   path or in the startup folder.
>
> Use the `-batch` option in non-interactive scripting or command line
>   work flows. Do not use this option with the `-r` option.
>
> To test if a session of MATLAB is running in batch mode, call the
>   `batchStartupOptionUsed` function.
>
> Example: `-batch "myscript"`

Answer (score 4):

I created a basic shell script called `runm` and put in my path:

```
$ runm mymatlab.m
```

Script:

```
# simple script to run matlab script
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "please pass m script"
fi

matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('$1');"
```